# Why aren't DIVs with given widths including paddings and borders by default?

Tags: css, padding

I've been using lately a CSS rule that I didn't know of, called `box-sizing`, which allow us to include the padding and the border of a box (`div`) in its given width (ex. 200px).

That way, we don't need anymore two divs to layout an area of content (one for the width, and another for the padding).

In my project, I found it so useful that I've been using it over and over: I gave the `div` a width and a padding, and the `box-sizing:border-box` property.

In fact, I used it to the point I asked myself, why isn't this a generic default property for the `div` html tag?

Unsure if I'm missing something here guys, I'd love to hear what you think.

```
.article{
    width: 600px;
    float: left;
    padding: 20px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: There is no `-ms-box-sizing` by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the standard has historically always defined width and height to refer to content width and content height respectively. [`box-sizing: border-box` is relatively recent](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing) and [only came about as a result of an IE bug being loved by so many](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AscendedGlitch), and even then the default remains `content-box` for compatibility with previous specifications.